# Make multiple asynchronous calls(fire and forget calls) at once using Rx java Observable

Tags: java, spring-boot, rx-java, observable, callable

I have a list of downstream api calls(about 10) that I need to call at once asynchronously. I was using callables till now where I was using

```
List<RequestContextPreservingCallable <FutureResponse>> callables
```

I would add the api calls to this list and submit it at the end using executeAsyncNoReturnRequestContextPreservingCallables.

Using Rx java Observables how do I do this?

```
List<RequestContextPreservingCallable<FutureResponse>> callables = new 
ArrayList<RequestContextPreservingCallable<FutureResponse>>();

callables.add(apiOneConnector.CallToApiOne(name));
callables.add(apiTwoConnector.CallToApiTWO(sessionId));
....

//execute all the calls
executeAsyncNoReturnRequestContextPreservingCallables(callables);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of the `zip` operator. The `zip` operator can take multiple observables and execute them simultaneously, and it will proceed after all the results have arrived.

You could then transform these result into your needed form and pass to the next level.

As per your example. Say you have multiple API calls for getting name and session etc, as shown below

```
Observable.zip(getNameRequest(), getSessionIdRequest(), new BiFunction<String, String, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(String name, String sessionId) throws Exception {
            // here you will get all the results once everything is completed. you can then take these 
            // results and transform into another object and returnm from here. I decided to transform the results into an Object[]
            // the retuen type of this apply funtion is generic, so you can choose what to return
            return new Object[]{name, sessionId};
        }
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())  // will start this entire chain in an IO thread
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // observeOn will filp the thread to the given one , so that the downstream will be executed in the specified thread. here I'm switching to main at this point onwards
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Object finalResult) {
           // here you will get the final result with all the api results
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            // any error during the entire process will be triggered here
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
             //will be called once the whole chain is completed and terminated
        }
    });
```

You could even pass a list of observables to the `zip` as follows

```
    List<Observable<String>> requests = new ArrayList<>();
    requests.add(getNameRequest());
    requests.add(getSessionIdRequest());

    Observable.zip(requests, new Function<Object[], Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public Object[] apply(Object[] objects) throws Exception {
            return new Object[]{objects[0], objects[1]};
        }
    }).subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Object[] objects) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for the response..With zip operator it can take multiple observables & run them simultaneously.But it's currently holding the main thread until all this calls with zip is done and returned.
here is the flow of my implementation class:
  (step 1) some business logic
  (step 2)  system out print (before making the zip call) 
  (step 3) ------ this Observable zip call------ 
  (step 4) system out print (after making the zip call)
  (step 5) save current time to database

Comment: is there any way to have the entire call in step(3) run separately so that the program continues to step(4) while 
 step (3) is still going on parallely. I am aware about @Async annotations in spring boot that will allow this but 
 wanted to know if its possible to do so using RxJava Observable.

Comment: @Jack Sorry for the late reply. I have updated the answer with thread handling

Comment: Since I have given `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()` all the network calls in the `zip` will be executd in a background thread only and you will receive the final result in `onNext` in the `main` thread. So, There's no blocking of the `main` thread